# R function to compare columns

Tags: r, function

In R language I would like to create a function to view selected columns for comparison in the Viewer. Assuming my dataframe is df1:

```
compare_col <- function(x){
  select(df1, x) %>%
    View()
}
```

If I define the function by x, I can only put input 1 column.

```
compare_col <- function(x)

compare_col("col_1")
```

Only if I define the function by say x,y, then can I input in 2 columns.

```
compare_col <- function(x, y)

compare_col("col_1", "col_2")
```

How can I create a function that is dynamic enough to input in **any no. of columns?**

Comment: You may use `function(...) { select(df1, ...)}`  It can take both quoted and unquoted arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `rlang` package to achieve this.
This will allow you to input a string of column names using the `syms` and `!!!` operator which will splice and evaluate in the given environment dynamically as you require.

```
library(dplyr)
#library(rlang)
compare_col <- function(x){
  df1 %>% select(!!! syms(x)) %>%
    View()
}
compare_col(c("col1", "col2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realised, all I actually needed to do was vectorise the inputs when calling the function.

```
compare_col(c("col1", "col2"))
```